# Installing wordcountaddin with

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, r-markdown, word-count

I have been trying to install an RStudio addin to count words and characters in text in an R markdown document, `wordcountaddin`, in RStudio on Windows.

```
devtools::install_github("benmarwick/wordcountaddin", type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)
```

But I keep getting the following errors:

```
Error: Failed to install 'wordcountaddin' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: run `install.packages("covr")` and try and debug that, it is failing to install it as a dependency and throwing the error. Installing the dependency should give a clearer error message and a way to debug it

Comment: After running `install.packages("covr")`, I got an error message `...'sys' had non-zero exit. After running `install packages("sys"), it works perfectly. Thank you, @Snel23

Comment: Glad i could help :)